# edit an element value with condition

Tags: jquery

I have this code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.trackInputHours').change(function() {
            $(this).closest('.trackOn').nextAll('.trackOn').find('.trackInputHours').val($(this).val());
        });             
    });
</script>
```

and I'd like to change the value (with `val($(this).val())`) only if the value for that element is `??` or less than the new value.

Is it possible with a sort of condition into the val() ? Or which strategy is better?

Comment: do you have any live code? I didn't understand what you want...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`val`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) callback option.

```
$('.trackInputHours').change(function() {
    var changeVal = $(this).val();
    $(this).closest('.trackOn')
        .nextAll('.trackOn').find('.trackInputHours')
        .val(function(i, v){
            if (v == '??' || v < changeVal) // note: you may need to parse here
                return changeVal;
            return v;
        });
});
```

Comment: Seems to work! But why do you pass the variable `i` to the val function?

Comment: @markzzz - `i` is the current index in the stack of elements. Generally for callback functions that perform some action on an array, the index in the array is passed as a argument to the function.

Comment: ah ok...but here I could get rid that variable, no? :)